# How do chess openings officially get recognized?

Tags: opening

With so many combinations of moves possible, how do openings get recognized? For example, what is to prevent me from playing a series of moves and declaring it the `xaisoft gambit` or `xaisoft heart-attack`?  What organization officially recognizes openings?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no organization that officially names openings.  Generally, the first person to publish professional-level research for a sequence of moves gets to name it.

Many openings with modern names were first played 200 years ago.

Answer (score 7):

An opening is named after successful professional USE by a world class player, in world class events.

Many "openings" are played by amateurs, either accidentally or on purpose, that don't get names. But if a line is played in high level tournaments by X, and X wins a large percentage of his games, people come to recognize it as X's opening, and name it after him or her.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to publish it professionally to have an opening named under you.

Take the example of the recently played Grunfeld defense in the game 1 of WCC 2012 Anand vs Gelfand.

It's a little-known fact that the first person to play Grunfeld defence was a [Moheschunder Bannerjee in 1855](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%BCnfeld_Defence), but because Ernst Grunfeld used it to stun Alexander Alekhine at Vienna in 1922; hence, the opening was named after Grunfeld.

If you end up using it in a popular/famous duel then also it can be named after you.

Comment: Correct.  If you're a leading GM and play it in a tournament, then that can happen.  I believe that qualifies as publishing professional research.  Besides, who would have the brass to say, "Look at this move by GM X! I name it after ME!"   A person doing this would be mocked.  Now, if the opening gains no further attention for many years, then it can be done.